# How to override Sonata Media Bundle templates?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I'm currently using `SonataAdminBundle` for the creation of a Back Office and I've integrated `SonataMediaBundle` (app-dev version) 2 days ago. The edit/create template from sonata bundle however has some errors! I've fixed them (and they are just twig errors).

But I can't just make the changes in the vendor. What is the correct way to overwrite the `SonataMediaBundle` templates?
I've tried the classic `AdminBundle` way but it doesn't work! here's the code:

```
sonata.admin.media:
        class: Acme\AdminBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Media Library", label: "Media" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - ~
            - ~
            - @sonata.media.pool
        calls:
            - [ setTemplate, [edit, AcmeAdminBundle:Media:edit.html.twig]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, now I've figured it out. In order to overwrite the media Preview or form, you should overwrite the form widget, or customize your form theme.

Example:
In the config.yml file add the configuration:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            # other files
            - 'AdminBundle:Form:mediaPreview.html.twig'
```

The media preview file should look something like this:

```
{% block sonata_media_type_widget %}
      << your code here >>
{% endblock sonata_media_type_widget %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite them in the same way you would any other bundle except Sonata use's easy extends so in App/Resources create a folder called ApplicationSonataMediaBundle or ApplicationSonataAdminBundle and inside this folder create a folder of the same name as the one you are trying to override.

For example I currently use the following:

```
App/Resources/ApplicationSonataNewsBundle/translations/SonataNewsBundle.en.xliff
```

To override any of the English translations in their news bundle OR

```
App/Resources/ApplicationSonataUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
```

To override their Layout template.

I would suggest you need to create something along these lines.

```
App/Resources/ApplicationSonataMediaBundle/views/MediaAdmin/edit.html.twig
```

and copy the Sonata code into it, then modify as you require.

Hope this helps