# Correct way to override default template in Sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata

I'm a bit confused as I've seen a few varying methods posted online.

I have a bundle created with easyextends in src/Application/Sonata/SonataMediaBundle, which extends the SonataMediaBundle in the vendors.

The default template displays

```
   This is the gallery index template. Feel free to override it.
   This file can be found in SonataMediaBundle:Gallery:index.html.twig.
```

so I've added src/Application/Sonata/SonataMediaBundle/Resources/views/Gallery/index.html.twig in my bundle

and this works and overrides, so why all these various other ways like [How to override Sonata Media Bundle templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080549/how-to-override-sonata-media-bundle-templates)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct way. To quote from symfonys [How to Override Templates from Third-Party Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html)

> To override the bundle template, just copy `index.html.twig` template from the bundle to `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig` (the `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle` directory won't exist, so you'll need to create it). You're now free to customize the template.

And for more detailed/ complex overriding behaviour have a look at [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html)

I wouldn't worry to much about other solutions unless you are not able to get the results you require using this method but I cant think of one.